# Generating PWM using Scilab

Tags: scilab

I am using the following codes in Scilab to generate Pulse Width Modulation using vectorization method.But I am getting undesirable plot while varying the number of cycles,TimePeriod,percent.Could any one help me in this?

```
percent=input("Enter the percentage:");
TimePeriod=input("Enter the time period:");
Cycles=input("Enter the number of cycles:");

x=0:Cycles*TimePeriod;
t=(percent/100)*TimePeriod;

for n=0:0.01:Cycles
    y(((n*TimePeriod)< x) & (x<(n*TimePeriod+t))) = 1;
    y(((n*TimePeriod+t)< x)& (x<((n+1)*TimePeriod))) = 0;
    plot(y,'b','LineWidth',2)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code and now it works. Your code was very slow due to the for loop with many many calls. (Scilab and Matlab are optimated to do matrix operations. So they weaken in loops. I reduced the number of calls to the number of cycles.

```
percent=input("Enter the percentage:");
TimePeriod=input("Enter the time period:");
Cycles=input("Enter the number of cycles:");
ts = 0.01; // sample time

x=ts:ts:Cycles*TimePeriod;
on  = ones(1, percent/100*TimePeriod/ts);
off = zeros(1, (1 - percent/100)*TimePeriod/ts);
signal = [];
for cycle = 1:Cycles 
signal = [signal, on, off];
end

figure(1)
plot2d(x, signal);
```